# Switch between button with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have this User Interface

[image]

When the i go on the page on the first time the 2 buttons appear as you can see above. When i check the checkbox the Save button appears and the other one disappear (how i wants) and vice versa

The problem is that at the first i want only 1 button appears that is the "Save Changes"  Button. This is my code:

```
   <hr>
        <?php

        $conn=ConnectToSql();

        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_countries";

        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn ,$query1)
        or die ("Error in query" . mysqli_error($conn));

          $choose = '';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
            {

                $choose .= '<option value = "'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
  <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Country">Choose a country:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
              <select class="form-control" name ="reg_country" >
                  <option selected></option>
                  <?php echo $choose;?></select>
          </div>
            </div>
    <br><br><br>

    <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
              <input type="checkbox" name="change" id="change"  value="0" > Change All Countries 


        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    <br>

    <hr>
```

This code the switch between rows and columns:

```
    <tr type="hidden" id="rowhidden" class="rowhidden">

                    <td >All Countries</td>
                    <td><select class="form-control"  name ="monday_all" > 
                        <option></option>
                        <option value = "Open">Open</option>
                        <option value = "Close">Close</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><select class="form-control"  name ="tuesday_all" > 
                        <option></option>
                        <option value = "Open">Open</option>
                        <option value = "Close">Close</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><select class="form-control"  name ="wednesday_all" > 
                        <option></option>
                        <option value = "Open">Open</option>
                        <option value = "Close">Close</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><select class="form-control"  name ="thursday_all" > 
                        <option></option>
                        <option value = "Open">Open</option>
                        <option value = "Close">Close</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><select class="form-control"  name ="friday_all" > 
                        <option></option>
                        <option value = "Open">Open</option>
                        <option value = "Close">Close</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><select class="form-control"  name ="saturday_all" > 
                        <option></option>
                        <option value = "Open">Open</option>
                        <option value = "Close">Close</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td><select class="form-control"  name ="sunday_all" > 
                        <option></option>
                        <option value = "Open">Open</option>
                        <option value = "Close">Close</option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>
            </table>


             <?php
             }
             ?>
```

This is the script:

```
      $("#change").change(function(){

        //row  
        $("#tablecountry tr.row2").toggle(!this.checked);
        $("#tablecountry tr.rowhidden").toggle(this.checked);

        //button
        $(".country-specific").fadeIn("slow").toggle(!this.checked);
        $(".country-all").fadeIn("slow").toggle(this.checked);

        });
            $("#change").change();



And 2 buttons with the id country-all and country-specific.
```

Now i have 2 problem :

1. At first i need to show 1 button then they will switch with the checkbox
2. At first i want a default value from the dropdown list. For example Malta.(you can choose malta from the dropdown list so it is already exists in the dropdown list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery script you're trying to get reference to **IDs** *#country-specific* and *#country-all* which doesn't exists (you used class attribute twice but there is no id attribute).

```js
$("#change").change(function(){
        

        $("#tablecountry tr.row2").toggle(!this.checked);
        $("#tablecountry tr.rowhidden").toggle(this.checked);
        $(".country-specific").fadeIn("slow").toggle(!this.checked);
        $(".country-all").fadeIn("slow").toggle(this.checked);

        });
$("#change").change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="change">
<div class="form-group country-specific">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" name="updated" class="btn btn-default">Save Changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group country-all">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" name="update-all" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i made the code your like yours can you tell me why the save button is working but the save changes button is not working, and another question i need to make that source in the script tag ?

Comment: i made the question above sorry but i have another problem because when the user choose a country from the the dropdown list the two buttons are showing i need only the save changes button to appear

Comment: 1. What do you mean "button not working"? Fade effect?
2. I extracted JavaScript code for clarity. Of course you can put script in script tag, but better way is store all scripts in .js files and include it into website by script tag.

Comment: @SigmondGatt I don't know what can I say, because code which you showed in your question don't explain all context.

Comment: yeah i know can i have your email addres to show you the code please because i cant post code here :/ im very sorry for wasting your time